# phpmailer class with yandex mail

Tags: email, phpmailer, yandex

I'm using phpmailer class for my website forms. But **YANDEX MAIL** with phpmailer sending mail not working.
But two days ago its worked. I was try  all combinations.

For example : "ssl", "tls", "port change" , but i'ts not working. Example my code :

```
         $mail->IsSMTP();

         $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // or "tls" (I was try)

         $mail->Host = "smtp.yandex.com.tr"; or "ssl://smtp.yandex.com.tr"(I was try)

         $mail->Port =587; or "465,25,587"(I was try)

         $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  or "false"   

         $mail->Username = "email@mywebsite.com";

         $mail->Password = "mypassword";

         $mail->From = "email@mywebsite.com";

         $mail->FromName =$email;

         $mail->AddAddress("goto@mywebsite.com");
```

Thanks all answers

Comment: You don't say how it's not working - what error messages or symptoms are you seeing? Valid protocol/port combinations are `ssl`/`465` (deprecated), `tls`/`587`, and occasionally  `tls`/`25`. Telnetting to port 587 on their server certainly works, so I'd go with `tls`/`587`. `Port` should be an integer value. The code you posted won't actually send anything, so I assume you have more code you have not posted.

Answer (score 6):

I was also struggling about that. Below is verified, working settings. But also you need to login to Yandex and accept eula or something thru https://mail.yandex.com before trying these settings.

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.yandex.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPOptions = array (
    'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

For my case my company's firewall blocks the smtp. I connected with my personel hotspot then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issues. I have found working solution:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.yandex.ru';
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->Username = 'user@yandex.ru';
$mail->Password = 'PasswordGoesHere';
$mail->setFrom('user@yandex.ru', 'Username');
$mail->addAddress($mailToAddr);
$mail->CharSet = "Windows-1251";
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = nl2br($message);
$mail->AltBody = $message;
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    // email sent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As for now (June 2021) to use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) with [Yandex](https://yandex.ru/) you should do the following:

First, prepare your Yandex account. They have pretty clear [instruction](https://yandex.ru/support/mail/mail-clients/others.html#smtpsetting), but in Russian. Here it is in short:

1. On "Mail → All settings → Email clients" page check "Use a mail client to retrieve your Yandex mail - From the imap.yandex.com server via IMAP" and "IMAP authorization method - App passwords and OAuth tokens".
2. On "Account management" page in "Passwords and authorization" section select "Enable app passwords" and create new application password.

Then you can use SMTP endpoint `smtp.yandex.ru:465` with `SSL` encryption enabled and the application password like this:

```php
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.yandex.ru';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS; // public const ENCRYPTION_SMTPS = 'ssl';
    $mail->Username = 'EMAIL@yandex.ru';
    $mail->Password = 'PASSWORD';
    $mail->setFrom('FROM_EMAIL@yandex.ru', 'FROM');
    $mail->addAddress('TO_EMAIL@yandex.ru');
    $mail->Subject = 'SUBJECT';
    $mail->Body = 'BODY';
    $mail->send();
```

You can avoid creating the application password and use your account password by checking "IMAP authorization method - Portal password" on "Mail → All settings → Email clients" page, but it is not recommended by the service.